# Should I replace the customized configuration file '/etc/gnome/defaults.list'?

Tags: gnome, upgrade

While upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10 I was prompted with a difficult decision:

Difference between the files

```
--- /etc/gnome/defaults.list    2014-10-13 05:52:59.320350092 +0300
+++ /etc/gnome/defaults.list.dpkg-new   2014-05-13 12:34:12.000000000 +0300
@@ -202,6 +202,9 @@
 text/spreadsheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop
 text/tab-separated-values=libreoffice-calc.desktop
 text/x-comma-separated-values=libreoffice-calc.desktop
+text/x-c++hdr=ubuntusdk.desktop
+text/x-c++src=ubuntusdk.desktop
+text/x-xsrc=ubuntusdk.desktop
 text/x-chdr=gedit.desktop
 text/x-csrc=gedit.desktop
 text/x-dtd=gedit.desktop
@@ -259,4 +262,3 @@
 x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop
 x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop
 x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird.desktop
-x-scheme-handler/bitcoin=armory.desktop;armorytestnet.desktop;armoryoffline.desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your addition is only one line, and since the unselected version will also be saved alongside irrespective of which option you choose, replace the customized version with the new one and add yours over after the upgrade finishes. The sole line you added would be:

```
x-scheme-handler/bitcoin=armory.desktop;armorytestnet.desktop;armoryoffline.desktop
```